# How can I take different property types and pass them to my HtmlExension method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, generics

I am using MVC 4.0 with C# 4.5.

I have a scenario where I have a view mostly containing static text but with some data from the model as well. I must keep the text in a .resx file and some examples may look like this:

- Sometimes I need no extra values so I just take this string
- Sometimes I just need a single extra value like {0} this
- Sometimes I need a list because the entry has {0} values like this {1}

I have an attribute that loads values from the .resx file; these decorate the ViewModel.  The three example above would look  like this:

```
    // 1 -EgOne would = string.empty
    [Label("RESX_EXAMPLE_1")]
    [StringTemplate("RESX_EXAMPLE_1_VALUE")]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string EgOne { get; set;  }

    // 2 -EgTwo would = "davy"
    [Label("RESX_EXAMPLE_2")]
    [StringTemplate("RESX_EXAMPLE_2_VALUE")]  
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string EgTwo { get; set; }

    // 3 - EgThree would bethe list
    [Label("RESX_EXAMPLE_3")]
    [StringTemplate("RESX_EXAMPLE_3_VALUE")]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public IList<string> EgThree
    {
        get
        {
            this.instalmentValues.Add("foo");
            this.instalmentValues.Add("bar");

            return this.instalmentValues;
        }
    }
```

In my view the usage is:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EgOne, "ResourceLabel")
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EgTwo, "ResourceLabel")
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EgThree, "ResourceLabel")
```

I'd like to keep the above as close to this as possible.

And 'ResourceLabel' simply has `@Html.StringTemplateFor(model => model)` for the moment.

So, I would like to have an Htm;Extension that ideally supports all three scenarios for various types that may be used in the View Model.

```
public static IHtmlString StringTemplateFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
                                                                   Expression<Func<TModel, 
                                                                   IEnumerable<TProperty>>> expression)
 {        
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var attribute = // comes from the aforementioned attribute

        return new HtmlString(attribute.StringTemplate.FormatInvariant(((IEnumerable<TProperty>)metadata.Model).ToArray()));
 }
```

You can see from the return statement that I am trying to take the values in the metdata.model and squirt them into the string returned by the .resx attribute so sometimes it will have no value, sometimes it will have one and sometimes it will be a list.

I hope this is clearer.  I can provide more info if required.

Comment: Bit unclear what you doing here. What is `attribute.StringTemplate.FormatInvariant(...`? - the code you have shown does not even declare `attribute`

Comment: @Stephen - sorry, I tried to remove some code for brevity - it could essentially be any code.  I need to know if is possible if I can use a list<T> anywhere in that method instead of the List<string>.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use something like `@StringTemplateFor(m => m.SomeProperty)` where `SomeProperty` is `List<T>`? If so then yes, but its not clear what you want to do with that data.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace `TProperty` with `IEnumerable<TProperty>` you get something like this

```
public static IHtmlString StringTemplateFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> expression)
{
    return new HtmlString(
        attribute.FormatInvariant(((IEnumerable<TProperty>)metadata.Model).ToArray()));
}
```

Comment: thanks.  I have tried this but I'm getting an error: The type arguments for HtmlExtensions.StringTemplateFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TProperty>>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I will update the question